# Should I install IBM Domino with domain or local admin account?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have recently deployed Active Directory in our firm and been pretty new to administrating it. I am starting to use Domain Administrator on all computer and it's really cool. 
But should I install servers, like for example IBM Domino with domain administrator account or is it better to use local admin? What are the disadvantages of using domain admin account? 
I am thinking about password change. If I use domain admin and change password, do I steel need to change passwords in scheduled tasks and services?

Comment: What does the documentation recommend?

Comment: @joeqwerty
nothing: [Installing Domino on Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/inst_installingdominoonwindowssystems_t.dita?lang=en)

Comment: Actually, it's a common question. I can be any other server system running   with the administrator account.